# Añadir classpath en un proyecto de android

Tags: android, build.gradle

Estoy haciendo una app en android y vi [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17230764/8081356) para un error que tenia, el caso es que al final del todo dice:

> In the above program, you have to change the domain name, username,
>   password and file path of the remote machine. To work with the above
>   program we need to add the following jar files int the classpath.
>
> ```
> commons-vfs.jar
> commons-logging.jar
> ```

El problema es que no se ni donde ni como añadir `commons-vfs.jar` y `commons-logging.jar` en mi proyecto de android.

¿Se puede añadir o tengo que descargar algo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para agregar archivos .jar a tu proyecto es necesario incluirlo en el folder `/libs` del proyecto, si no existe tienes que crearlo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si usas otra IDE como eclipse, automáticamente se registra el jar cuando es copiado dentro de este folder, pero en el caso de usar **Android Studio**, se tiene que agregar la referencia `build.gradle`, en la raiz del archivo agrega la sección `dependencies` y agrega dentro:

```
compile files('libs/<nombre archivo .jar>')
```

---

ejemplo:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    ...
    compile files('libs/OoyalaSDK.jar')
    compile files('libs/OoyalaIMASDK.jar')
    compile files('libs/FlowTextView_1.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/jorgesyspowder.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsoup-1.7.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/OoyalaSDK.jar')
    compile files('libs/berkeleytheet.jar')
    compile files('libs/OoyalaIMASDK.jar')
    compile files('libs/ima-android-v330.jar')
}
```

Comment: Que vista tienes en android studio para que te aparezca `libs` debajo de `build`? a mi no me aparece. Me aparece dentro de `app`

Comment: Cambia a "proyect", también puedes crealo manualmente en windows explorer o finder.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno tendrás que descargar las librerías, para agregarlas a tu proyecto Android deberás hacer lo siguiente:

1. Pon las librerías en tu carpeta libs.
2. Después vas a la parte superior de tu android studio. Clic en Build -> Edit Libraries and dependencies.
3. Se abrirá una venta, en la parte superior derecha de esa ventana encontraras el signo de **+** das clic y seleccionas la opción 2 **Jar dependency**
4. Buscas las librerías que quieras agregar, claro esta la que pusiste en Libs.
5. Guardas cambios y espera a que termine el gradle.

otra forma mas rápida, cuando agregues tus librerías a la carpeta libs vas directo a tu archivo gradle, al final pones los siguiente:

```
dependencies {
    //Aquí están tus otras librerías
    //al final de esto agregas lo siguiente
    compile files('libs/nombre de la libreria.jar')
}
```